# Export specific menu

Tags: export

How can I export a specific menu out of wordpress? I have a list with many URLs and I need to copy it to multiple sites. But I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You could export "all content", save and edit the XML file to remove the posts and pages, leaving the menu.

Comment: Nice idea. But don't really help because the xml data is saved in chronological order. So i would need to search every link :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wordpress plugin to do this.
[WordPress Menu Exporter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/)

#### This hasn’t been updated in over 2 years but still it works fine.